# Nullmailer with gmail saying user/pass not accepted but swaks can send test fine

Tags: server, email, gmail, smtp

So that's it in a nutshel.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTC with nullmailer and mailutils installed.

Tried a few different remotes configs but currently at:

smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=465 --auth-login --user=MyActualEmail@gmail.com --pass=TheRandomStringFromAppPassByGoogle --ssl

I've tested with swaks with those same credentials and got the test email just fine.

Is there a way to see more verbose logging with null mailer, so maybe I can see the communications with the server like I can with swaks?

Thanks,

Gilligan

Answer (score 1):

Ended up needing to add /etc/allmailfrom and put my gmail address in there.

remotes ended up with:

```
smtp.gmail.com smtp --port=587 --starttls --auth-login --user=EMAILADDRESS@gmail.com --pass=RandomShitGoogleAppPassGives
```